# Internet explorer sents different utf-8 url parameters, that breaks the page

Tags: laravel, internet-explorer, search, get, angular5

For example when I type in a ä,ö, or ü character into a searchÖ
for IE I get something like this for an ä character:

```
...?page=1&limit=8&search=Ã¤
```

for for chrome nad firefox its this for an ä character:

```
...?page=1&limit=8&search=%C3%A4
```

the controller recieves null as a paramenter from IE and the right character from Chrom and firefox.

I'm using Laravel as a backend and Angular 5 for the frontend

Comment: How are you loading this url? You should encode the characters yourself.

Comment: @jerodev how to I do that? by using encodeURI() or..?

Comment: Depends on how you are currently building the url

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the [encodeURI](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURI) function to encode the url, then, refer to [this article](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urldecode.php) and [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40160574/laravel-5-decode-post-method-url) to use the urldecode method to decode the parameters.

Comment: is there a way without the encodinURL

Comment: Maybe, it's the easiest way to transfer the parameters to the [html entities](https://www.w3schools.com/charsets/ref_html_entities_4.asp), otherwise, perhaps you need to change it by yourself.